# Присвоение значения переменной из файла

Tags: c++

Есть переменная размером в 2 байта, нужно присвоить ей значение напрямую из файла с определенного адреса в двоичном режиме. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Перейти в нужную позицию в файле (я так понимаю, это вы подразумеваете под адресом?) и прочесть... Интересно, например, информация о том, файл текстовый или бинарный - это, как в анекдоте о таксисте, не наше дело? :)

Comment: @Harry Да, с позиции.

Comment: Можно через winapi.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Очередное "зачем просто, если можно сложно"? Автор вообще-то и об операционке ни слова не сказал. Впрочем, он вообще немногословен :) Соответственно, как и ответы - когда не на что отвечать...

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков мне нужно чтобы приложение работало на windows linux mac

Comment: 1) Какой адрес? 2) Что за переменная? || Где вы здесь Вангу видели? Указывайте конкретнее, пожалуйчта

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG адресс любой, переменная типа `uint16_t`

Comment: я предлагаю сделать пру простых запросов в гугле, как открыть файл, как перейти в нужную позицию и как прочитать n байт, не ужели это настолько сложная и непонятная задача чтоб задавать подобные вопросы? если не получится приходите с кодом, вам подскажут что не так

Comment: @ЯрикДаркнетович ну так у линукса тоже апи есть. У mac наверняка тоже, но делать прогу под апл это вообще проблема, а пользователей с ним мало.

Comment: @Arenoros Если я буду просто записывать в файл данные обычным методом то цифры превратятся в их символьные варианты, мне нужно чтобы записались все 16 бит переменной, и потом я мог успешно их прочитать.

Comment: что значит "обычно"? при чём тут запись когда вы про чтение спрашивали? так же вы так и не указали в каком формате у вас данные в этом самом файле

Comment: @Arenoros сори моя беда, запись по сути мне не особо нужна, главное понять как файл по битам разобрать и потом впихнуть эти биты в переменную.

Comment: ок, если вы на столько отказываетесь искать информацию которой полно в интернете, вот подсказка вам нужно всего 4 функции fopen fseek fread и fclose

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что байты считываются в вектор, а файл является `std::ifstream`
Тогда:

1. Открываем файл: `file.open("Адрес файла", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);`
2. Переходим к нужной позиции `file.seekg(pos)`, где `pos`- абсолютная позиция в файле
3. Заводим вектор `std::vector<unsigned char> input;`
4. Размечаем вектор на **2** байта: `input.resize(2)`
5. Считываем в вектор: `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(input.data()), input.size());`

Вообще, авторам следует конкретизировать данные в вопросах, а также иногда пользоваться гуглом.
Один из первых запросов по `ifstream` - https://purecodecpp.com/archives/2751 - там все есть.